# Split Email:passrwords to list of emails and list of passwords

Tags: java, split

lets say i have a TextArea that contatins Email:password -in that way- in each line.
I want to split emails and passwords to list of emails and list of passwords.
how can i do that?

Comment: You already mention `split`, have you tried to use it so far?

Comment: yes but im not sure how to do it because i usually wirte `mail = textArea1.getText().split("\\r?\\n");` `pass = textArea2.getText().split("\\r?\\n");` to spilt each line and each of them were in a differnt TextArea. my potato head cant comprehend how to do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `split` to first split at all linebreaks, then to split each line at the `:`. Of course you might run into trouble if the password contains a `:`, but that is a different task.

```
    String text = textArea.getText();
    String[] lines = text.split("\r?\n");
    List<String> users = new ArrayList<>(lines.length);
    List<String> passwords = new ArrayList<>(lines.length);
    for(String line:lines) {
        String[] userAndPass = line.split(":");
        users.add(userAndPass[0]);
        passwords.add(userAndPass[1]);
    }
```

assigning `text` to an example input of `"u1:p1\nu2:p2\r\nu3:p3"` and putting a `System.out.println(users +"\n"+ passwords);` at the end will print:

```
[u1, u2, u3]
[p1, p2, p3]
```

Comment: yeah, if the passwords contain `:` in it i will make it split the text just once. right?

Comment: Why is handling : in the password a different task?

Comment: @AwniAhmed yes, use indexOf and substring in that case.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson because it is not mention in the requirements. Also i consider this a pretty extensive answer already for a "i have tried nothing at all" question.